# how to match height of a row widget which is tallest among other widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've defined a Row of column widgets but unable to match height of other widgets defined in a Row

I have tried with Expand , Intrinsic Height, width, Contrained box, and defining containers inside each column.

Expected Results are to match height with parent/other row widgets[enter image description here][1]

```
Widget columnOne(String t1, String t2) {
 return ClipRRect(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
child: Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Padding(
          padding:
          EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(t1,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    fontFamily: 'FJ',fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                )),
          )
        ),
      ),
      IntrinsicHeight(
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
          child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(t2 ,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.parent,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Colors.black,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        )),
                  ))),
        )
      )


    ],
  ),
),
 );

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfYOl.png 
Current result If I change text/overflow the text

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9MTK.png
Expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the design, the bottom of the card can only be one or 2 lines high.
In this case, it’s easier not to rely on the automatic height, but to use fixed values.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math.dart' as v_math;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: RowExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RowExample extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<List<String>> entities = [
    ['22', 'fdslfdssdf'],
    ['22', 'sdfdssf fd fasdf '],
    ['3242', 'sdsf'],
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: entities.map((item) => columnOne(item[0], item[1])).toList(),
    );
  }

  Widget columnOne(String t1, String t2) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
      child: Container(
        height: 130,
        width: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 70,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(t1,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 30,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'FJ',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  )),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(t2,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.parent,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            )),
                      ))),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I thought that the static height and width will be a bad idea for different screen sizes, being a native dev i always use match/wrap, min height,min width etc, anyway, will take this as a solution now. Once again thanks for your effort. if you have any other ideas sharing the automatic heights and widths with you please tag this queston which help others as well.

Comment: Added Kherel. I figured out the solution, please check and upvote my question.